# Flot : Stack are fill custom pattern or texture

Tags: flot

In vertical stack area in flot chart. how to fill pattern instead of fill color ? is there any way we can apply own css or fill images in the stack area.

Answer (score 1):

You can put anything you want behind the flot placeholder and have the canvas be transparent.

Set the option for `grid.backgroundColor = null` and you'll get what you want:

```
var options = {
     grid: {
        backgroundColor:null
     }
};

$.plot($('#placeholder'),data,options);
```